# Mount NAS on Boot (WDCloud EX2)

Tags: networking, ubuntu, nas

I have a WDCloud( EX2 ) NAS for several years, which works fine with MAC os and Windows 7- via Wifi and LAN.

Now- I have an i5 with 8GB, 1000MB LAN connected to network, installed with fresh copy of Ubuntu18.04 on an SSD drive.

When using Windows machine on LAN, typical speed is roughly 40MB/Sec, and same for MAC on wifi ( maybe a bit less ).

When connecting Ubuntu machine using `Files`, connection speed was 40-80 MB/Sec, as others, but since I want it mount automatically on boot, I used the following code, which caused a much slower speed of 4MB/Sec.

The following is part of `.sh` file I wrote to make it create all mounts automatically :

`//192.168.2.100/Multimedia/Music $dir2 cifs credentials=/home/$USER/.smbcredentials,iocharset=utf8,gid=1000,uid=1000,file_mode=0777,dir_mode=0777 0 0`

Can someone tell what can cause this to slow its connection?
Connection speed shown in Ubuntu's settings is `1000 MB/s`